# issue with memcached with random output

Tags: php, memcached

I just try a simple test in memcached which is running on my ubuntu server

```
<?php 
//Test Memcached

$string = 'Hello World';

$memcached = new Memcached(); 
$memcached->addServer('127.0.0.1', 11211);

if($memcached->get('test-memcached')){

    echo 'test 1';
}else{

    echo 'test 2';
    //Set in cache for 5 min
    $memcached->set('test-memcached', $string, time() + 300);   

}
?>
```

Sometimes the output is ' test 1 ' and sometimes it is ' test 2 ' but before the 5 min of the expired cache

Comment: make sure of your timezone

Comment: my timezone is ok